# equivalent date_part function in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have a sql statement to extract date object. It runs fine in Postgres but not sas. Part query is like this:

```
(case when date_part('month',run_date)::integer < 10 
     THEN '0'||
          date_part('month',run_date)::varchar(1)||
          date_part('year',run_date)::varchar(4)
     else  date_part('month',run_date)::varchar(2)||date_part('year',run_date)::varchar(4)
     end) as our_date
```

In sas, there's no date_part function. I tried datepart function. But it's not performing the same functionality. How could I make that sql statement run in sas? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DATEPART](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245883.htm)

```
data have;
 timestamp='01JAN2012:08:48'dt;
run;

proc sql;
 select datepart(timestamp) format=mmddyy10., 
 timepart(timestamp) format=time.,
 month(datepart(timestamp)),
 year(datepart(timestamp))
 into :date , :time, :month, :year
 from have;
quit;

%put DATE: &date;
%put TIME: &time;
%put MONTH: &month;
%put YEAR: &year;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use

```
MONTH(run_date)
```

and

```
YEAR(run_date)
```

Comment: I tried MONTH(run_date) within proc sql, and it returns null value ("." in sas).

Comment: I think I know why I got the null value. Because run_date is not a regular mmddyy10 format, but it shows format as DATETIME20. Guess I'll have to convert that first.

Comment: The `month()` and `year()` functions are designed to be run against a date value.  Running them against a datetime value will usually result in a null value because of the differences in the way dates are stored compared to datetimes in SAS.