# How do I extract the month and year from dates in a date column, within SAS?

Tags: sas

I formatted the date column within my table, using the following code;

```
data data1;
set data;
format Date ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

I want to know how I can create a new column within my table which just extracts the month and year from the dates in the "Date" column.

How do I do this please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equivalent date\_part function in sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416282/equivalent-date-part-function-in-sas) - specifically, the second answer.

Comment: @user667489 Okay. But the other question does not give me an idea of how to extract the day number from the date. Do you know?

Comment: @Jed perhaps I missed the part in your question where you asked for "the day number from the date", by which I assume you which day of the month. In the answer you have been referred to by @user667489, if `month()` gives you the month and `year()` gives you the year, would like to infer what function would give you the day?

Answer (score 0):

in order to create new columns calculated by existing Date column you should try this:

```
data data1;
set  data;
format Date ddmmyy10.;
yearNo=year(Date);
monthNo=month(Date); 
run;
```

Comment: And if you want to have only base and new colls you may add

keep Date yearNo monthNo;

statement before "Run;"